# Remove brackets in Python REGEX

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I have the txt file as follows:

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100 22921
2.179.103.97 - lind8584 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:36 -0700] "POST /grow/front-end/e-commerce/robust HTTP/2.0" 304 14641
```

I tried this:

```
host = re.findall('^(.*?)\-',logdata)
username = re.findall('\-(.*?)\[',logdata)
_time = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', logdata)
request = re.findall('\"(.*?)\"',logdata)
```

but the results end up like this, everything is between brackets

```
'host': ['146.204.224.152 '],
'user_name': [' feest6811 '],
'time': ['21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700'],
'request': ['POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1']},
```

How can I remove them.

Full code:

```
import re
def logs():
    result = []
    with open('assets/logdata.txt') as f:
        lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
        for logdata in lines:
            host = re.findall('^(.*?)\-',logdata)
            username = re.findall('\-(.*?)\[',logdata)
            _time = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', logdata)
            request = re.findall('\"(.*?)\"',logdata)
            result.append({'host':host,'user_name':username,'time':_time,'request':request})
    return result
```

Comment: The problem isn't with regex, it's that `findall` returns a `list`. Access the `[0]`th element of the list to get the result string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` instead of `findall`

```
import re
def logs():
    result = []
    with open('assets/logdata.txt') as f:
        lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
        for logdata in lines:
            host = re.match('^(.*?)\-',logdata).group(1)
            username = re.match('\-(.*?)\[',logdata).group(1)
            _time = re.match('\[(.*?)\]', logdata).group(1)
            request = re.match('\"(.*?)\"',logdata).group(1)
            result.append({'host':host,'user_name':username,'time':_time,'request':request})
    return result
```